# intriguing Polytope

Tags: gr.group-theory, convex-polytopes, permutations

Define $E_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to be the canonical basis (that is all elements set to zero except the entry $i,j$ )
let the bloc matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ defined by :

$M = \begin{pmatrix}E_{\sigma(i), \sigma(j)} \end{pmatrix}_{ 1\leq i,j \leq n}$
for some permutation $\sigma$ of ${1,2,..,n}$

can you find the convex hull of this set of points ?
Or at least is the number of equations that define this polytope is exponential?

Case $n=2,3$

[image: case n=3]

[image: case n=2]

the $x_i$ are such that they sum to $1$. That is, resulting matrices are the general form of some element from the convex hull.

From this experiment we can deduce that if a point $M$ is from the convex hull then it satisfy the equations:

- $\forall i \qquad$ $\sum_{k} (M_{i,i})_{k,k}=1$
- $\forall i \qquad$ the matrix $M_{i,i}$ is diagonal.
- $\forall i \neq j \qquad$ the diagonal of $M_{i,j}$ is zeros.
- $\forall i \neq j \qquad$ $\sum_{k,m}(M_{i,j})_{k,m}=1$
- $\forall i \neq j \quad \forall p \quad$ $\sum_{k}(M_{i,k})_{j,j}=\sum_{k} (M_{i,k})_{j,p}$
- $M$ is symmetric.

The question is, are they sufficient?

Comment: Which set of points in what space? Are the $M$ the points, in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ where $\sigma$ runs over all permutations?

Comment: yes the space is $\mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$

Comment: Could you describe the polytope for $n = 1, 2, 3$ perhaps?

Comment: Yes I wrote a program that compute the convex hull in case $n=1,2,3,4..$ I will post results today.

Comment: Could you add some words of explanation about the output of your script?

Comment: @j.c. Sorry I made a mistake I'll fixe it and explain

Comment: So we are looking at the convex hull of $n!$ points in $\mathbb{R}^{n^4}$. So for $n=1, 2, 3,$ the polytopes will simply be simplices of dimension $0, 1, 5$ assuming there is no relation between the points. For $n=4$ the dimension of the polytope spanned by $24$ points is $22$. I think it is very plausible, that the number of equations will be exponential in $n$. From $n=7$ it is the case that $n!>n^4$, so all cases before that might be somewhat exceptional.

Comment: .. in fact for $n=4$, the polytope you are looking for is the cyclic polytope of dimension $22$ with $24$ vertices. ..

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Can't see why it's the cyclic polytope for $n=4$

Comment: @RémyMartin I calculated it.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Can you please show me how you do the calculation.

Comment: @RémyMartin I put the coordinates in sage to obtain a polyhedron, take the affine hull and check for combinatorial equivalence with the cyclic polytope.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: Can it also test affine equivalence?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I guess for me 'cyclic polytope' is only defined up to combinatorial equivalence. If you want to test affine equivalence, you have to say to what cyclic polytope it should be affinely equivalent to.